# CSS styling not applying to the background image

Tags: html, css

I am creating an eCommerce website. I added two banners to my site. I want to display the banner image horizontally in the same line. but the problem is the banner image is showing vertically. One banner image appears below another image.

How to align those banner images horizontally?

[image]

```css
.banner-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  min-width: 580px;
  height: 50vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: url(img/banner/b17.jpg);
}

.banner-box2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  min-width: 580px;
  height: 50vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: url(/img/banner/b18.jpg);
}
```

```html
<section id="sm-banner" class="section-p1">
  <div class="banner-box">
    <h4>Crazy deals</h4>
    <h2>buy 1 get 1 Free</h2>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-box2">
    <h4>Crazy deals</h4>
    <h2>buy 1 get 1 Free</h2>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What, if any, CSS is applied to the `section`? BTW, I would suggest putting the common CSS into a third class that you can then apply to both `banner-box`es. Also, what CSS styling do you feel is not getting applied to your background image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must add css to your section

Here it is :

```
section.section-p1
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* this actually put your images horizontally */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a container to manage the image containers flow on your page. Since you didn't provide CSS for `section-p1`, I used that. Set its `display` to `flex` and `flex-direction` to `row` and style it from there.

Full guide on flex boxes here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Updated with Heretic Monkey's suggestion as well, using specificity so you don't have to repeat attributes for essentially the same class and just change whatever you need using subclasses (in this case, the images)

```css
.section-p1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.banner-boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  min-width: 580px;
  height: 50vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.banner-boxes.box1 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/350x350);
}

.banner-boxes.box2 {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/350x350);
}
```

```html
<section id="sm-banner" class="section-p1">
  <div class="banner-boxes box1">
    <h4>Crazy deals</h4>
    <h2>buy 1 get 1 Free</h2>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-boxes box2">
    <h4>Crazy deals</h4>
    <h2>buy 1 get 1 Free</h2>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean it this way?

```css
.section-p1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.banner-box{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    min-width: 580px;
    height: 50vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url(https://cc-prod.scene7.com/is/image/CCProdAuthor/product-photography_P3B_720x350?$pjpeg$&jpegSize=200&wid=720);
}

.banner-box2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    min-width: 580px;
    height: 50vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/4041392/pexels-photo-4041392.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);
}
```

```html
<section id="sm-banner" class="section-p1">
   <div class="banner-box">
      <h4>Crazy deals</h4>
      <h2>buy 1 get 1 Free</h2>
      <button>Learn More</button>
   </div>
   <div class="banner-box2">
      <h4>Crazy deals</h4>
      <h2>buy 1 get 1 Free</h2>
      <button>Learn More</button>
   </div>
</section>
```